# Access to parent scope in kendo template

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm try to access parent data scope in kendo grid template, is it a bad practice use "this.parentDataItem"? Or exist other ways? As final result in my example I want hide first column.

My Grid:

```
<div id="someGrid"
     data-role="grid"
     data-row-template="someTemplate"     
     data-bind="source: gridDataSource"
     data-columns="[
       { title: 'FirstColumn', width: '100px' },
       { title: 'SecondColumn', width: '100px'},
      ]">
</div>
```

My template:

```
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <tr role="row" data-uid="${uid}">        
    <td class="check-row"># if(this.isFirstColumnVisible) { # InvisibleText # } #</td>      
    <td class="check-row">VisibleText</td>
  </tr>
<script>
```

My model

```
{
  isFirstColumnVisible: false,
  gridDataSource: ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the grid's column collection have a visible property?

Comment: Yes it have. But I want common solution for template, not only grid. For example I have many items that I want to hide in template on render. So I can use visible bind, but it's redundantly bacause i don't whant dynamic show\hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

> parent().parent().myProperty